# Android emulator for small screen device

Tags: java, android, android-emulator

Hi i want to check my app on emulator that is on 2.7in and 3.2in.

can i do it with the android simulator? because it always open me a big emulator

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When creating a new AVD, you can specify a custom resolution:

[image]

You can also change the density to low (120dpi).

Comment: According to the [current CDD](http://source.android.com/compatibility/4.0/android-4.0-cdd.pdf) at least 426dp x 320dp. `px = dp * (dpi / 160)`. `426 * 120/160 = 320`. `320 * 120/160 = 240`. So 320 x 240 is the minimum assuming ldpi.

Answer (score 0):

Create a new virtual device and select a different resolution.

Answer (score 0):

Start the `AVD Manager` create a `New..` emulator instance, The window that appear has options for custom resolution.